# aws efs create-access-point command is not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, access-point

I tried to create an access point for my efs file system using following command:

aws efs create-access-point --file-system-id fs-0163391d24d0b14b5  --posix-user Uid=1001,Gid=1001  --root-directory Path="/mnt/",CreationInfo={OwnerUid=1001,OwnerGid=1001,Permissions="0755"}

This command is not working and giving following message:

"usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws  help
aws   help

Unknown options: Path=/mnt/,CreationInfo=Permissions=0755, Path=/mnt/,CreationInfo=OwnerGid=1001"

Please tell me what is wrong with this command ? I am using this command after referring to aws cli guide docs only.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `"`. It should be:

```
aws efs create-access-point --file-system-id fs-0163391d24d0b14b5 --posix-user Uid=1001,Gid=1001 --root-directory Path='/mnt,CreationInfo={OwnerUid=1001,OwnerGid=1001,Permissions=0755}'
```